# fatal error: ext/type_traits.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, c++, g++

Here is my error:

```
root@:lab1# g++ lab1.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from lab1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:62:29: fatal error: ext/type_traits.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

`/usr/include/c++/5/ext` is empty:

[image]

---

My guess is that this error is caused by missing files in that folder, but I don't know for sure. Maybe somebody knows how to re-download c++ headers?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So your question is why there is nothing in that directory?

Comment: Actually, my question is how to fix that error and my guess is that it is caused by missing files in that folder, but I don't know for sure.
Maybe somebody knows how to re-download c++ headers?

Comment: Have you tried simply re-installing the `libstdc++-5-dev` package?

Comment: @steeldriver - thank you very much, it works!
I just didn't know what I have to reinstall to make it work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling `libstdc++-5-dev` fixed this. [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) provided this solution [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862348/fatal-error-ext-type-traits-h-no-such-file-or-directory#comment1330705_862348):

> Have you tried simply re-installing the `libstdc++-5-dev` package?

– [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) [Dec 19 '16 at 19:07](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862348/fatal-error-ext-type-traits-h-no-such-file-or-directory#comment1330705_862348)

The original poster [confirmed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862348/fatal-error-ext-type-traits-h-no-such-file-or-directory#comment1331689_862348) that this solved the problem.

For the benefit of others who find this question by searching, one way to completely reinstall that package is to run:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install libstdc++-5-dev
```

The reason this is able to solve the problem is that the `libstdc++-5-dev` package provides [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) headers.